# Simplest Example of a Non-Deterministic Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, non-deterministic

I am looking for a very simple (potentially the simplest) example of a non-deterministic Turing machine for some "practical" task.

To give an example, I would like something similar to the binary counter for a deterministic Turing machine:

https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/turing-machine/four.html

But I couldn't find something on these lines for the non-deterministic case. I could find many artificial examples illustrating the concept, but I wanted something applied. I found these slides:

https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrc/Computability%20&%20Complexity/Lectures/C240Lec17.pdf

But the example on them does not seem very clear to me. For example, it is supposed to check primality, but seems to halt and fail in the first unsuccessful division.

If anyone has a suggestion, or otherwise could help me understand the above example, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Consider that all DFAs are Turing Machines, and that NFAs are likewise non-deterministic Turing Machines. NFAs are well suited for "ends with `w`"-style languages (i.e., all strings that end with `abbabbcabbbc`) that, when expressed as DFA are often quite ugly. These are trivial examples of non-deterministic Turing Machines, but examples nonetheless. Also, in the example you provided, slide 3 explicitly lists how acceptance and rejection work: a word is accepted if any run succeeds and is rejected if all runs succeed.

Comment: Perhaps what you're after is a nondeterministic Turing machine for an NP-complete problem? Such a machine could have better performance than the best known equivalent deterministic machine (so it wouldn't be trivial or contrived) and we know by the definition of NP-completeness that these exist (namely, nondeterministic Turing machines that solve a problem in polynomial time where the best-known deterministic TM takes superpolynomial time). Consider perhaps the string-related problems on the Wikipedia page? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems

Comment: Thanks for both answers! It is more or less on the lines I am thinking about.